How to include a compiled library .o dependency with f2py?
I want to call a compiled file geometry.o in a wrapped python module geometry3d with f2py like so :
FC="gfortran" f2py -m geometry3d -c geometry3d.pyf geometry3d.F90 -I/path_to_files/ geometry.o
When I try to import the new python package with import geometry3d the dependency is broken and the function in the submodule geometry.o is not found.
I use Python 3.12.6 and f2py 2.1.1.
I have 2 fortran files :
geometry3d.F90
module geometry3d
    use iso_c_binding
    use geometry ! Call the geometry module already compiled
    implicit none
contains
    real(c_double) function volume(base, height, depth)
        real(c_double), intent(in) :: base, height, depth
        real(c_double) :: area
        area = areat(base, height)  ! Call the areat function from the geometry module
        volume = area * depth
    end function volume
end module geometry3d

and
geometry.F90
module geometry
  use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
contains
  ! Sub routine to calculate the triangle area
  real(c_double) function areat(a, b) !bind(C, name="areat")
    real(c_double), intent(in) :: a, b
    areat = 0.5 * a * b
  end function areat
end module geometry

First I compile the geometry.F90 with
gfortran -O3 -fPIC -c geometry.F90
Then I generate the signature file :
f2py -m geometry3d -h --overwrite-signature geometry3d.pyf geometry3d.F90
Finally, I wrap the geometry3d.F90 file in python :
FC="gfortran" f2py -m geometry3d -c geometry3d.pyf geometry3d.F90 -I/path_to_files/ geometry.o
When I try to import the new python package with import geometry3d I have an error : "undefined symbol: __geometry_MOD_areat".
This error is confirmed with a terminal command nm geometry3d.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so | grep areat which gives "                 U __geometry_MOD_areat".
To solve the problem, I simply remove the include command "-I/path_to_files/ geometry.o" and add the geometry.F90 file in the last command :
FC="gfortran" f2py -m geometry3d -c geometry3d.pyf geometry3d.F90 geometry.F90 
But I am sure, there is another way to add an already compiled library, no ?

Welcome, I suggest  taking the [tour]. Use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Your code is not Fortran 90 but at least Fortran 2003.
